# Copy/move parent node to children with XSL stylesheet in ASP cassic

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

Given the following XML, I would like to add to the xsl file the ability to move/copy the `<OrderDate>` node to to the child of each `<OrderDetails>` node within its associated `<Orders>` parent node. So basiclly it should sort by date as already in the XSL and move/copy.
Not sure how to accomplish this. All attempts I have tried have come close but failed.

Starting XML

```
<xmldata>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
        <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
        <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum></PONum>
        <ShippingMethodID>502</ShippingMethodID>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDetailID>25676</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>58309-SYL</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
            <ProductName>ABCD</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>300</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDetailID>25677</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>ABCDEFG</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9757</ProductID>
            <ProductName>XYZ 2</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>300</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
        <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
        <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum></PONum>
        <ShippingMethodID>141</ShippingMethodID>
        <OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetailID>21472</OrderDetailID>
        <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
        <ProductCode>58309</ProductCode>
        <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
        <ProductName>XYZ 12V</ProductName>
        <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
        <Quantity>160</Quantity>
        <TotalPrice>760.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
     next Order...
    </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

and the following XSL

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xmldata>

  <xsl:for-each select="//Orders">
    <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(OrderDate,'/'),'/'),' ')" data-type="number" order="descending"/> <!-- year -->
    <xsl:sort select="substring-before(OrderDate,'/')" data-type="number"  order="descending"/> <!-- month -->
    <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(OrderDate,'/'),'/')" data-type="number" order="descending"/> <!-- day -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xmldata>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transformed XML

```
<xmldata>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
        <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum></PONum>
        <ShippingMethodID>141</ShippingMethodID>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDate>6/13/2013 5:08:00 PM</OrderDate>
            <OrderDetailID>21472</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>58309</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
            <ProductName>XYZ 12V</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>160</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>760.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
         <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
        <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum></PONum>
        <ShippingMethodID>502</ShippingMethodID>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
            <OrderDetailID>25676</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>58309-SYL</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
            <ProductName>ABCD</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>300</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
         </OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
            <OrderDetailID>25677</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>ABCDEFG</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9757</ProductID>
            <ProductName>XYZ 2</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>300</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
    next Order...
    </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- When we reach the xmlData element, copy it and select its Order children by reverse date order. -->
  <xsl:template match="xmldata">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Orders">
        <!-- year -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(OrderDate,'/'),'/'),' ')"
                  data-type="number"
                  order="descending"/>
        <!-- month -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(OrderDate,'/')"
                  data-type="number"
                  order="descending"/>
        <!-- day -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(OrderDate,'/'),'/')"
                  data-type="number"
                  order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Copy out the Orders element and its children, except for OrderDate. -->
  <xsl:template match="Orders">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::OrderDate)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Copy out the OrderDetails element and its children, adding the OrderDate for the Order. -->
  <xsl:template match="OrderDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../OrderDate"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>            
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input XML (which is based on your example, but I've changed one of the dates and the order of the Orders so that the sorting is more obvious):

```
<xmldata>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
    <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
    <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
    <PONum></PONum>
    <ShippingMethodID>141</ShippingMethodID>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>21472</OrderDetailID>
      <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>58309</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
      <ProductName>XYZ 12V</ProductName>
      <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
      <Quantity>160</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>760.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
    <OrderDate>6/13/2013 5:08:00 PM</OrderDate>
    <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
    <PONum></PONum>
    <ShippingMethodID>502</ShippingMethodID>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>25676</OrderDetailID>
      <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>58309-SYL</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
      <ProductName>ABCD</ProductName>
      <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
      <Quantity>300</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>25677</OrderDetailID>
      <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>ABCDEFG</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>9757</ProductID>
      <ProductName>XYZ 2</ProductName>
      <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
      <Quantity>300</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

produces the following output XML:

```
<xmldata>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
    <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
    <PONum />
    <ShippingMethodID>502</ShippingMethodID>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDate>6/13/2013 5:08:00 PM</OrderDate>
      <OrderDetailID>25676</OrderDetailID>
      <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>58309-SYL</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
      <ProductName>ABCD</ProductName>
      <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
      <Quantity>300</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDate>6/13/2013 5:08:00 PM</OrderDate>
      <OrderDetailID>25677</OrderDetailID>
      <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>ABCDEFG</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>9757</ProductID>
      <ProductName>XYZ 2</ProductName>
      <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
      <Quantity>300</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
    <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
    <PONum />
    <ShippingMethodID>141</ShippingMethodID>
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
      <OrderDetailID>21472</OrderDetailID>
      <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
      <ProductCode>58309</ProductCode>
      <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
      <ProductName>XYZ 12V</ProductName>
      <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
      <Quantity>160</Quantity>
      <TotalPrice>760.0000</TotalPrice>
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</xmldata>
```